# C# MVC - Send message with SignalR from server to Caller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have a request from client to Server using `SignalR-2.2.1`. After that request, Server will send the results back to the caller.
Here is my `JavaScript` code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myHub = $.connection.signalHub;
    myHub.client.receive = function (tmp) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(tmp);
        //do something
    };
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $('#xxxxx').click(function () {
            var form = $("form");
            form.submit();
            myHub.server.sendSomething();
        });
    }).fail(function (reason) {
       //do something
    });
});
```

And here is the code from my Server Side

```
public partial class SignalHub : Hub
{
    public void SendSomething()
    {
         Clients.All.receive(MyJson);
    }
}
```

When I use `Clients.All` function, it works perfectly fine. But what I want is the server only send the result back to the caller (the one that send the request).
So I change `Clients.All.receive(MyJson)` to `Clients.Caller.receive(MyJson)`. After I change it, now the client doesnt update the content. Do I need to specify my receive function in client side that it would receive something different?

Comment: No, that should work. Anything in browser console?

Comment: @Mark check my answer

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen its like the function is not called in javascript. theres nothing in Console / log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that since you are calling `form.submit();` you are probably navigating away from the page or possibly reloading it, in that sense a new connection with a different "connectionId" is established between the new/reloaded page, thus the message intended for `Client.Caller` is lost since it is associated with the connection established on the page that you navigated away from or refreshed.

You might want to consider posting your form-data using AJAX instead of a full form submit.

Comment: I also tried to send the Connection ID after form submit, and send it back from server using `Clients.Client(connectionID).receive(MyJson)` but it still the same. I will try using AJAX and update the result

Comment: its working perfectly fine now. so the problem was in the `form.submit()`. After I changed it into `AJAX call` and render the page with the result, the SignalR is working ok now. Thx a lot,