# SignalR disconnected with POST request on IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer, firefox, signalr

I'm setting up a notification system on my website (ASP.NET MVC). It needs to be stateless so I picked SignalR. 
Notifications come from the server side only and I want to show it after refreshing a new page, not in real time. Usually it's an ActionResult that will be triggered and send a notification to client, then redirects or shows a view.

This is the way it proceeds:

1. The server sends message to the client.
2. The client stores it to browser local storage.
3. After redirect, it show notifications from local storage.

I'm using SignalR 2.2.1 with JQuery 1.9.1

NotificationHub.cs

```
[HubName("notificationHub")]
public class NotificiationHub : Hub
{
    public static void Send(string connectionId, string name, string message)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificiationHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).sendNotification(name, message);
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml js

```
<script>
getNotificationStack = function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem("notifications") != null) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notifications"));
    }
    return [];
}

checkNotification = function () {
    var notificationStack = getNotificationStack();

    var count = notificationStack.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        window.alert(notificationStack.pop());
    }
    localStorage.removeItem("notifications");

}

initHubConnection = function () {
    // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;

    var notification = $.connection.notificationHub;
    notification.client.sendNotification = function (name, message) {
        var notificationStack = getNotificationStack();
        notificationStack.push(name + ": " + message);
        localStorage.setItem("notifications", JSON.stringify(notificationStack));
    };

    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        // allows to send notification to one tab through connectionId
        document.cookie = "connectionId=" + $.connection.hub.id;
    });
}

$(function () {
    checkNotification();
    initHubConnection();
});
</script>
```

MyView.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestSendNotification", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Press that button"/>
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult TestSendNotification()
    {
        NotificiationHub.Send(Request.Cookies["connectionId"].Value, "Info", "Oh you pressed that!");

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

It works like a charm with Chrome, but not with Microsoft Edge and Firefox.

**Microsoft Edge behavior:**
Connection is made but client does not get the message.

-> Note: if I debug my app and wait long enough after sending notification, I get the message successfully.
It seems that sending message takes too long, then the page is refreshing so connection is lost and client cannot get the message...

**Firefox behavior:**
Every time I click the button (= sending POST), connection is lost, and of course client cannot get messages. I have no idea why it does that!

If I'm using ajax POST, it works well, but that's not what I'm looking for.

##############################################################

**Update 16th Feb. 2017:**
Unfortunately we cannot use simple http POST with this library, it has to be ajax POST in order to work properly. 
Got an answer on their git: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3869#issuecomment-280074464

Comment: Hi barbara, I had the same problem with firefox too. It seems that after sending submit (POST) function, signalR will create a new connectionID for the client. the way I fixed it is using AJAX POST rather than submit button.

Comment: Hello Mark, thank you for your comment. Glad to hear that I'm not the only one... but I cannot use ajax post instead of POST unfortunately :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39197967/c-sharp-mvc-send-message-with-signalr-from-server-to-caller  here was my question. I had tried many things and came with nothing. AJAX POST was the only solution I got. why you cannot use ajax post?

Comment: The project I work on is not new, thousands of ActionResult methods using Session for notifications. The idea was to get rid of Session and use another system for that. I cannot change the way I'm posting my forms. It works well on Chrome so I don't see why it doesn't with Firefox or IE.

Answer (score 0):

We had to deal with this issue as well.

The solution is: keep track of new and old connectionIds.
Inside a controller:

```
public ActionResult RegisterConnectionId(string newConnectionId, string oldConnectionId)
{
    Session["SignalRConnectionId"] = newConnectionId;

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldConnectionId))
        RemapConnectionId(newConnectionId, oldConnectionId);        
}
```

We introduced an expiring MemoryCache as a victim cache for old ConnectionId's.

```
public void RemapConnectionId(string newConnectionId, string oldConnectionId)
{
    if(newConnectionId != null && newConnectionId != oldConnectionId)
        MemoryCache.Default.Set(oldConnectionId, newConnectionId, ...);
}
```

You can get the current ConnectionId from an old one and take care of potential MULTIPLE changes like this:

```
public string ResolveConnectionId(string connectionId)
{            
    while (!IsEligibleConnectionId(connectionId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionId))
        connectionId = MemoryCache.Default.Get(connectionId) as string;


    return connectionId;
}
```

Of course, you need to provide the new and the old connection ids to the server when the hub starts.